# Viewing an HTML page generated by a Java Servlet

Tags: java, html

I have the following supplied code:

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import javax.servlet.*; 
    import javax.servlet.http.*; 

    public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet { public void doGet(HttpServletRequest                 request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException { 
        /* set the output content type */ 
        response.setContentType("text/html"); 
        /* create a class to write the output */ 
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        /* write an html document */ 
        out.println("<html>"); 
        out.println("<head>"); 
        out.println("<title>HelloServlet</title>"); 
        out.println("</head>"); 
        out.println("<body>"); 
        out.println("<h1>Hello, from my first servlet!</h1>"); 
        out.println("</body>"); 
        out.println("</html>"); 
      } 
    }
```

I can compile this using a custom version of Dr. Java, but when I try to run it, I get the following error: "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]."

Should I be using a another application like XAMPP to see the results or was I given code that is incorrect?

Comment: So, servlets are not standalone Java applications.  They run inside a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty.  I'd recommend looking up some servlet tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using like tomcat 7, to run it on local server. Also maybe add an url mapping to you're doGet method. Also if you rather use eclipse, you would save yourself for lots of trouble, there are a eclipse version out there for web developers.

Comment: I have Eclipse and I had trouble running it. Perhaps I have the wrong version. I'll check into it!

Answer (score 0):

Servlets would get called from other classes.
Based on the action mentioned on HTML form, doGet or doPost methods of servlets will get called.

so if you just want to test your servlet functionality, just add a code segment like

```
public void main(string[] args){
   doGet(\*required params to call get*\);
}
```

additionally you don't know whether servlet would be called by Get or POST but you have same functional requirement for both. Then adding this code segment would be advisable

```
public doPost(\*args*\){
   doGet(\*args*\)l
}
```